# trigger events on inner polygons on outer polygon event with svg

Tags: jquery, svg, polygon

I have a svg where i have multiple segments made up of sectors.The sectors toggleclass on click and change color. I need the inner sectors to lighten up on click event of the outer sectors

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/rawatdeepesh/xzs2umgd/) is the fiddle link for the same.

I tried giving classes like herbalLvl1 ,herbalLvl2, herbalLvl3 so I could trigger click event on herbalLvl1 if HerbalLvl2 or HerbalLvl3 was clicked. But these sectors already had a class and I need these to have just one class to toggle with dynamically created class as below :

[image: Here is the image]

```
    var myclass=$(this).attr("class");
    var classarray=myclass.split(" ");
    var currentClass=classarray[0]; var thisClass=classarray[0];



var res=currentClass.split("clicked");
if(res.length==1)
    {
      $(this).removeClass(thisClass);
      $(this).addClass(currentClass+'clicked');
      console.log($(this).attr("class"));

    }
    else
    if(res.length==2)
    {
        console.log('2');

        $(this).removeClass(thisClass);
        $(this).addClass(res[0]);
        console.log($(this).attr("class"));
    }
```

If I add another class to the polygon then `$(this).addClass(res[0]);` will return different values since class gets removed in below fashion:

page Load:herbal herbalLvl1

click select: herbalLvl1 herbalclicked

click unselect: herbalclicked herbalLvl1clicked

n so on, because the newly added classes gets appended in the end.

Is there a way to achieve selecting of inner rings on selection of outer other than applying multiple classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT** *(Or second answer!)*
Since the hability to deselect a polygon is obviously necessary...

You'll notice that the deselection is a bit more complex than the just a selection.
Why?

Because a select also selects all it's "parents".
But a deselect *may* not deselect its parents because *maybe* another sibling is selected...

So got to check for that case!

I included as many comments as possible within the code.
;)

Your mouse will love [**This Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/Bes7weB/fcar1z55/).

```
$("polygon").click(function() {

  var myclass = $(this).attr("class");
  var classarray = myclass.split(" ");
  var currentClass = classarray[0];

  // If the polygon clicked (the trigger) already has the "clicked" class ( Not a "UNIQUE" , see below for those )
  if ($(this).hasClass(currentClass + 'clicked') && $(this).attr("data-sub") != "UNIQUE") {
    console.log("already selected");

    // Remove the "clicked" class.
    $(this).removeClass(currentClass + 'clicked');

    // Get the class and branch.
    var thisSub = $(this).attr("data-sub");
    var thisLevel = $(this).attr("data-level");

    // Filter elements based on level and sub branch.
    var foundAnother = false;
    var foundEl = [];

    // Filter function for each element of the current class.
    $("." + currentClass).filter(function() {

      // If the element has the same sub AND the same level as the current class.
      if (($(this).attr("data-sub") == thisSub) && ($(this).attr("data-level") == thisLevel)) {

        // If this element has the "clicked" class ( So another element that has same sub and level AND that was aleready clicked ).
        if ($(this).hasClass(currentClass + 'clicked')) {
          console.log("found another");
          foundAnother = true;

          // May be many elements... So push it to an array.
          foundEl.push($(this));
        }
      }

      // Keeping anyway all elements of the same sub in this filter. The found elements will be re-clicked later.
      if ($(this).attr("data-sub") == thisSub) {
        return true;
      }

      // For all element kept in the above, remove the "clicked" class. --- End filter function.
    }).removeClass(currentClass + "clicked");

    // Another check on each current class -> If there is element still having the "clicked" class except the "UNIQUE", set a flag.
    var checkAll = false;
    $("." + currentClass).each(function() {
      if ($(this).hasClass(currentClass + "clicked") && $(this).attr("data-sub") != "UNIQUE") {
        checkAll = true;
      }
    });

    // If flag was'n raised in the above, remove the "clicked" class for ALL elements.
    if (!checkAll) {
      $("." + currentClass).removeClass(currentClass + "clicked");
    }

    // If some elements were found having the same sub and level as the trigger.
    if (foundAnother) {
      console.log(foundEl.length);

      // Click them all !! (Kind of a short cut here!)
      for (i = 0; i < foundEl.length; i++) {
        foundEl[i].click();
      }
    }

    // This else is for "UNIQUE" elements that have "clicked" class. So if a  "UNIQUE clicked" element is clicked -> All the ellements having this current class should be unclicked.
  } else if ($(this).hasClass(currentClass + 'clicked') && $(this).attr("data-sub") == "UNIQUE") {
    console.log("UNIQUE FOUND");
    $("." + currentClass).removeClass(currentClass + "clicked");

    // Last else. If the trigger was not already clicked before.
  } else {

    // Add the appropriate "clicked" class.
    $(this).addClass(currentClass + 'clicked');

    // Markup error check... Since maybe it's the very first click it gets, have to check if it has all the required data atributes.
    if (typeof($(this).attr("data-level")) == "undefined") {
      console.log("data-level is missing");
      return;
    }
    if (typeof($(this).attr("data-sub")) == "undefined") {
      console.log("data-sub is missing");
      return;
    }

    // Get the class and branch from this target.
    var thisSub = $(this).attr("data-sub");
    var thisLevel = $(this).attr("data-level");

    // Filter elements based on level and sub branch.
    $("." + currentClass).filter(function() {
      if ((($(this).attr("data-sub") == thisSub) || ($(this).attr("data-sub") == "UNIQUE")) && ($(this).attr("data-level") < thisLevel)) {
        return true;
      }
    }).addClass(currentClass + "clicked");
  }
});
```

---

**First answer** *(doesn't include the hability to deselect)*

What if you use another attribute, instead of `class`, to distinguish the "level" and the "branch" ?

Like this : `<polygon class='herbal' data-level="2" data-sub="A"...`
So a letter for each different "branches"...
And when the "level" has only one "branch", set `data-sub` to "UNIQUE"`.

Have a look at this [**updated Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/Bes7weB/hkkpjbg3/).

Code:

```
$("polygon").click(function() {

  var myclass = $(this).attr("class");
  var classarray = myclass.split(" ");
  var currentClass = classarray[0];

  // Add the appropriate "clicked" class.
  $(this).addClass(currentClass + 'clicked');

  // Markup error check.
  if (typeof($(this).attr("data-level")) == "undefined") {
    console.log("data-level is missing");
    return;
  }
  if (typeof($(this).attr("data-sub")) == "undefined") {
    console.log("data-sub is missing");
    return;
  }

  // Get the class and branch.
  var thisSub = $(this).attr("data-sub");
  var thisLevel = $(this).attr("data-level");

  // Filter elements based on level and sub branch.
  $("." + currentClass).filter(function() {
    if ((($(this).attr("data-sub") == thisSub) || ($(this).attr("data-sub") == "UNIQUE")) && ($(this).attr("data-level") < thisLevel)) {
      return true;
    }
  }).addClass(currentClass + "clicked");
});
```

Comment: This seems to be a better workaround, but could we achieve toggleClass with the same setup so that the sectors could be selected/unselected as well while making sure the inner circle gets unselected if none of its outer rings are toggled back to unselected. Also I am not sure of what the below code does :
 `$("." + currentClass).filter(function() {
    if ((($(this).attr("data-sub") == thisSub) || ($(this).attr("data-sub") == "UNIQUE")) && ($(this).attr("data-level") < thisLevel)) {
      return true;
    }
  }).addClass(currentClass + "clicked");`
Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: This part "filter" the `$("." + currentClass)` collection based on the condition. So it keeps the element if it fits. I will check for the "unselect". ;)

Comment: Wow... It was tricky!!! I found the way. Check this [**Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/Bes7weB/fcar1z55/) and if it's ok, I will edit my answer and add some comments to clarify this quite complex code. ;) Still a glitch... Hold on.

Comment: Wow,amazing job Louys,just one concern, on selecting any ring lvl3, the lvl 2(no matter how many) and inner ring LVL1(just 1) should be selected.However while unselecting ring lvl3, if no of selected outerring lvl3 ==0 then its inner rings shuld be unselected as well.,there is no partition in lvl2 rings that belong to a particular group(lvl1).

Comment: I think just fixed it... Re-check ;) (Same second Fiddle)

Comment: Hi Matt, sorry for multiple comments,it has been fixed except that any Lvl3 select should select all Lvl2 rings that belong to the particular Lvl1 ring. Could you please update it in a new version of the previous fiddle so I could check this fiddle as well.
here is the SS for the issue: http://tinypic.com/r/25r16r6/9
thanks a lot!!

Comment: Ok... Now I get it... mmm. This is sure possible. I will check this. Hold on.

Comment: On second thought: This breaks the "hierarchy" concept... Let say that all LVL2 are highlighted on a LVL3 selection. What happens if there's a click to unselect the non-parent LVL2 ?

Comment: Hi Louys,Thanks for your views on this.In case there is a click to unselect LVL2 ring , all the level3 should be unselected as well,similarly any lvl3 ring selection should select all lvl2 and the single lvl1 ring as well from the same group, just a note same color rings are under one group.
thanks a lot!

Comment: This is the answer I was expecting... So now, another question: What will be the difference between LVL2 and LVL1 in this case? Should you just skip this level? By just drawing your LVL1 wider in order to skip the level 2 ? (Than, LVL3 would be LVL2 !!... But aligned with the other LVL3). ..... And those other questions: Do you really need to split the LVL2 ? What is the LVL2 for? What's the use-case?

Comment: Thanks again , Lvl 2 could have subcategory description belonging to the LVL1 so that we could have maximum detail in the design,eg,brand1 has 2 categories, and lvl3 has the products associated with brand.

Comment: Hoping I'm on the way to get it ................................................................. So it's like narrowing a selection. If I select LVL1, all LVL3 are possible. If I select a LVL2, all LVL3 are still possible (?). And if I select a LVL3, you have the narrower selection. **But** after I have selected a LVL3 and then I deselected a LVL2, my LVL3 selection is deselected because all LVL2 are parent of each LVL3 ???

Comment: Okay... Understand that I have to undertand the logic to code it ;) Another way to see it is that for each LVL3, both LVL2 are needed. But the objective is to ultimately select a LVL3. Maybe user doesnt know which LVL3 to select. So he selects one LVL2 because he knows (without knowing the other LVL2 is needed anyway to get a LVL3!) **But** if he selects one or more LVL3, both LVL2 MUST be selected. If user deselects a LVL2, it deselects all LVL3. ------------------------------------ I'm I on it now?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129663/discussion-between-rawatdeepesh-and-louys-patrice-bessette).